# frame.Eval(script) not returning the results in WatiN

Tags: watin

`string result = frame.Eval(javaScriptCode)` not returning the results in WatiN.

But it is working fine for `browser.Eval(javaScriptCode)`

Comment: Is this a normal Frame or an iFrame? IE or FireFox? This will help me reproduce your issue so I might solve it

Answer (score 0):

If the page in your iframe has linked to another domain, you cannot execute javascript code for that frame. That is restricted by your browser to prevent CSS (Cross site scripting).

If you try to execute javascript code in such an iframe, you probably get "permis

To get more details about CSS, read this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)